# Apache Superset unable to create plugin

Tags: apache-superset, yo

I'm trying to create a custom plugin for my superset, but when when I run **npm install -g yo** command in my terminal, I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/conf/index.js:128
                        throw err;
                        ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/root/.config/insight-nodejs/insight-yo.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:394:35)
    at Conf.get store [as store] (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/conf/index.js:108:18)
    at Conf.get (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/conf/index.js:47:27)
    at Insight.get optOut [as optOut] (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:52:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:208:48)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/root/.config/insight-nodejs/insight-yo.json'
}
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Run the command as root user as below

```
sudo npm install -g yo
```